# Licensing and Obfuscation software

Tags: software-development, obfuscation

I'm currently searching for a affordable solution for Licensing and Obfuscation. My budget is very low (I'm a student). I turned my attention to LogicNP's CryptoLicensing and CrpytoObfuscation. Both tools are obviously (as far as I read) very good and have all the features I need.

I would purchase it, but sadly it looks like this company does not exist anymore. Or is inactive or whatever.

I tried to contact them 3 times and I searched their page carefully. It looks like that there are no news since July 2013. Earlier there had been regular updates but one year without happening anything? I don't get any response, not even a notification that my mails were read.
And I don't want to pay for software which is already slightly outdated and will become so the next time...

So does anybody know software similiar to those which do not cost more? ~$500 USD is already a huge bunch of money.

The only alternative to CryptoObfuscation I know is RedGate's SmartAssembly which costs in it's simplest version more than I can afford. I could try to ask for discount, but I guess it won't be much cheaper...

An alternative for both would be: http://xheo.com/products/copy-protection/pricing
But that's too expensive, too.

So what do you guys know? Any good solutions? Obviously the prices are all made for huge companies, not for start-ups :-/

EDIT: Okay, today I got a response from LogicNP.

Comment: What if you trust your customers not to steal your products, under good faith? People with DRM get their stuff pirated MORE than those without it.

Comment: what language/tools are you using to make your product? what is the purpose of the product? and what is the selling price of your product?

Comment: It's purely written in C#. Hmm, I'm don't believe that non-DRM stops piracy. The problem is, I want to have different editions. The program I'm writing is very comprehensive, so one price for all would be bad. It should be available for people with low budgets (<100$) as well as bigger companies. In order to accomplish this, I will need DRM. And surely, I do trust. I believe most people would actually buy it. But that's just one part of all.

Answer (score 3):

[ArmDot](https://www.armdot.com/) is a good tool for obfuscation and license key making. This tool allows you to create and verify license keys.

Answer (score 0):

[.NET Reactor](https://www.eziriz.com/dotnet_reactor.htm) and [IntelliLock](https://www.eziriz.com/intellilock.htm) offer both, licensing and obfuscation. The price for a corresponding single developer license is 179$.